# ckati regenerating even if it was not changed

Tags: android, build-system

I'm building some Android modules and I often get:

> (ANDROID TREE)/prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ckati was modified,
>   regenerating...

It usually takes 7 minutes and doesn't change anything (even timestamp of **ckati** binary doesn't change). I have workarounded this by modifying:

> (ANDROID TREE)/build/soong/ui/build/kati.go

and adding:

```
"--regen_ignoring_kati_binary",
```

However I still wonder why does it happen? Is it code issue related to time stamp checking in:

> (ANDROID TREE)/build/kati/regen.cc

or am I missing something?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I am also puzzled myself... Have you come across an answer to this?

Comment: I have a feeling it might have something to do with this issue on github, even though it is closed, the description matches the problem: https://github.com/google/kati/issues/53